# IAR Macro porting on GCC

Tags: gcc, macros, arm, iar

I am trying to port a code written using IAR compiler for ARM Cortex-M series device on GCC.

There is a macro in IAR complier

```
 __INTRINSIC __nounwind
```

I am not able to find any reference to this. What does it mean, how to port this macro on GCC compiler.

Comment: Usually, *unwinding* refers to stack traversal.  So this marks the function code space (or maybe stack slot) as something that shouldn't be traversed.  Did you look on line for the IAR documentation?

Comment: Documentation for the compiler says `__intrinsic` is for internal compiler use. Why do you need it? What kind of code are you trying to port?

Comment: This is related to lwip, there is an ethernet device driver port. I think I will have to apply with some different technique